# How does a program execute with respect to the operating system?

Tags: operating-systems

I am reading Operating Systems by William Stallings 6th edition and I came across this text,

### Program execution:

```
A number of steps need to be performed to execute a
program. Instructions and data must be loaded into main memory, I/O devices
and files must be initialized, and other resources.
```

Now I am unable to understand how I/O devices and files are initialized on program execution? I assume it meant to start the I/O resources but what about the files? Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A initialized file means that you have comprobe that exist, or open it in some mode (write, read, r&w, etc) and create it if is not already.

Comment: You mean if a person wants to perform an operation on the file then that file must be loaded into the operating system with respective rights?

Comment: The file must be loaded by the operating system into main memory. Usually when editing a file it is created a modified copy under a different name. The file permissions are evaluated before editing or creating